# Mismatched entity and/or field definitions on "Address Field" after upgrade

Tags: 10, upgrading

After upgrading from Drupal 9 to Drupal 10 the status page shows the following Entity/field definitions error:

```
 Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
**Order report**

    The Address field needs to be updated.
```

Normally running "drush entup" fixes field definition errors but doing so here doesn't work and processes the following error:

```
 The SQL storage cannot change the schema for an existing field (billing_address in commerce_order_report entity) with data.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`drush entup` is no longer supported, use `drush updb` instead. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742

This is rather an update error of the Address module which can be updated independently from core, it is compatible with Drupal 9 and 10 simultaneously.

The previous version had update hooks which are no longer present in the current version, but you need to run all update hooks via `drush updb` in the correct order. Roll back the module version and catch up drush updb for the previous version and then again for the current version because this has a schema change as well.